# Go text/template templates: how to check value against an array of values within the template itself?

Tags: arrays, go, templates, conditional-statements

Let's say you have a JSON value like `{ "Fruit": "apple" }` as your input before applying the template. I want to check that the value of "Fruit" is in a set of `[]string{"pear", "banana", "grape"}` and do something or not do something depending on whether the value is in the set.

So, input to template:

`{ "fruit": "apple" }`

Template (assume containsVal is a custom function we pass in to the template that accepts a string and a slice of strings):

`{{ if containsVal .Fruit []string{"banana", "grape", "etc"} }}do stuff{{ end }}`

It seems the templates don't allow string slice literals in them -- template fails to compile.

Apparently you can define a struct and pass that into .Execute(). Or I could hard-code my values in the `containsVal` function.

But for my purpose, I want the values to be **dynamic** and **in** the template, not hard-coded in Go code. So someone else should be able to come along and have a different set of values to check against ("fig", "cherry", etc.) by updating the template text.

I've poked around https://pkg.go.dev/text/template and google and am not seeing any way to do this. I have only been able to do simple equality against simpler variables, like string == string in the templates.

Thanks.

Comment: Does a variadic function work?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco not sure how to do one of those (new to Go)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use "if" statement with "or" and "eq" operators like as:

```
    tmplText := `
    {{ if eq .Fruit "banana" "grape" "etc" }}
        {{ .Fruit }} exists in the list
    {{ else }}
        {{ .Fruit }} doesn't exist in the list
    {{ end }}
`

    tmpl, err := template.New("").Parse(tmplText)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, map[string]interface{}{
        "Fruit": "apple",
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Comment: Certainly, I edited that.
Thank you so much @CeriseLimón

Comment: Thank you @Hossein Daneshvar ! That definitely works. What wasn't working for me earlier was trying to pass multiple arguments to a custom function. But this does exactly what I need it to do and it's even simpler/easier to update than a custom func.

Comment: Hmm.  Where is "or" in the example, @HosseinDaneshvar? Is it somehow implicit?

Comment: Hi @Marvin,
It’s there:
if eq .Fruit "banana" "grape" "etc"

by go document:

For simpler multi-way equality tests, eq (only) accepts two or more arguments and compares the second and subsequent to the first, returning in effect

so for
arg1==arg2 || arg1==arg3 || arg1==arg4
you can write as : eq. arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4